# jq: How do I reshape into an object, using multiple selects as values?

Tags: json, key, jq

**JSON**

```
[
      {
        "name": "username",
        "value": "my-username"
      },
      {
        "name": "password",
        "value": "my-password"
      }
]
```

**Desired Result**

```
{ "username": "my-username", "password": "my-password" }
```

**A few failed attempts**

`.[] | { username: select(.name == "username").value, password: select(.name == "password").value }`

No output

`.[] | { username: select(.name == "username").value} + { password: select(.name == "password").value }`

No output

`.[] | { username: select(.name == "username").value } + .[] | { password: select(.name == "password").value }`

Fails

If I only want a single field, the syntax works fine. E.g.

`.[] | { username: select(.name == "username").value  }`

produces

`{ "username": "my-username" }`

The only issue is trying to do the same with multiple elements.

Thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens, jq (version 1.5 or later) already understands the `{"name":_, "value":_}` method of representing a JSON object, so you can achieve the result simply using the jq filter:

```
from_entries
```

Comment: Thanks @peak! I'd already accepted @hobbs' answer when I read this, and I appreciated his going into some detail on the fundamental problems with my approach and on the zen of .[] in general. However, you could argue that your answer, which focuses on `from_entries`, is a more clear and direct answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your expression starts with `.[] |` and then the thing after the `|` produces an object, then you must be producing 0 or 1 objects *per element of the array*. But you know that that's not what you want. You want one object, so you should be starting by producing an object.

```
{ 
    username: (.[] | select(.name == "username").value), 
    password: (.[] | select(.name == "password").value) 
}
```

is similar to what you're currently doing, but it works.

You could also do `map({ key: .name, value }) | from_entries` as a nicer way to do the same thing: it uses jq's builtin `from_entries` to turn an array of key/value pairs into an object. You just have to change your `name` key into `key`, which is what `from_entries` expects.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for the clarity on `.[] |`. in addition to providing winning recipes.

`from_entries` does look like it's just what I want, especially since `name` and `value` happen to already be my key names.

Incidentally, I'm also interested in producing `{ "my-username": "my-password" }`. I currently have `.details.fields | from_entries | { (.username): .password }` working, but I feel like I am taking 1 step too many.